# Log-convexity of a function defined by an integral (Normal Mills ratio)

Tags: inequality, gaussian-integral, convexity-inequality

Let's define $f(x)$, for all $x>0$ by :

$$f(x)=e^{x^2/2}\int_x^{+\infty}e^{-t^2/2}dt$$

I would like to prove that $f$ is log-convex, which is equivalent to the following condition :

$$\forall x>0,f''(x)f(x)-f'(x)^2\ge0\tag{$\star$}$$

Simple calculations lead to :

$f'(x)=xf(x)-1$

$f''(x)=(x^2+1)f(x)-x$

$f''(x)f(x)-f'(x)^2=f(x)^2+xf(x)-1$

Hence, in order to prove $(\star)$, it is sufficient to prove that :

$$\forall x>0,f(x)\ge\frac12\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x\right)$$

and I didn't find any way to show this last inequality.

Comment: And it’s _Mills’s_ ratio.

Comment: Just in case that you are interested: Here is a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4835476/42969.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to prove that, for all $x> 0$,
$$\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}\int_x^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t
\ge \frac12\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x\right)$$
or
$$g(x) := \int_x^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t - \mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\cdot \frac12\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x\right) \ge 0.$$

We have
$$g'(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\left(\frac{x^3 + 3x}{2\sqrt{x^2+4}} - \frac{1 + x^2}{2}\right) < 0, \quad \forall x > 0.$$
Also, we have $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 0$.
Thus, $g(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0$.

We are done.

Comment: I simply don't understand why I couldn't see this alone. Thank you very much. And well done :)

Comment: @Adren You are welcome.

Comment: Just in case that you are interested: Here is a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4835476/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. It is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

OP's function $f(x)$ is not some "function defined by an integral" but the well-known Mills ratio for the Normal distribution:

$$f(x) =e^{x^2/2}\int_x^{+\infty}e^{-t^2/2}dt = \frac{\int_x^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-t^2/2}dt}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-x^2/2}}$$
$$=\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}=\frac{\Phi(-x)}{\phi(x)} \equiv m(x),$$

where $\Phi$ is the Normal distribution function and $\phi$ is the Normal density, $\Phi'(x) = \phi(x)$.

Various results have been established over the years for the Normal Mills ratio. In particular,

**Birnbaum, Z. W. (1942)**. "An inequality for Mill's ratio". *The Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, 13(2), 245-246.

proved that

$$m(x) \geq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4} - x}{2},$$

...which is exactly what is needed for log-convexity of $m(x)$.

Mills ratio is a good illustration that the ratio of two log-concave functions (as $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are), may not be log-concave. In general, this is because the logarithm of such a ratio is the *difference* of two concave functions, which is equivalent to the sum of a concave and a convex function (since "minus-concave" is convex).

Comment: Thank you @Alecos Papadopoulos for this very intersting precision !

Comment: Just in case that you are interested: Here is a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4835476/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I will look it up.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the solution from

- Z. W. Birnbaum. "An Inequality for Mill's Ratio." The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 13(2) 245-246 June, 1942.
  https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177731611

(already cited in [Alecos Papadopoulos' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4834255/42969)). Instead of Jensen's inequality we apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the functions $g(t) = e^{-t^2/4}$ and $h(t) = te^{-t^2/4}$:

$$
 \left(\int_x^\infty t e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \right)^2
< \int_x^\infty  e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \cdot \int_x^\infty t^2 e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \, .
$$
The inequality is strict because $g$ and $h$ are not constant multiples of each other.

Evaluating the first integral and integration by part for the last integral  gives
$$
 \left(e^{-x^2/2} \right)^2 < \int_x^\infty  e^{-t^2/2} \, dt \cdot 
\left( x e^{-x^2/2} + \int_x^\infty  e^{-t^2/2} \, dt\right)
$$
or
$$
 1 < f(x) \cdot ( x + f(x)) \, ,
$$
so that
$$
f''(x)f(x)-f'(x)^2=f(x)^2+xf(x)-1 > 0 \, .
$$
This proves that $f$ is (strictly) log-convex.