# Monotonicity of a function involving Normal cdf

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution, monotone-functions

I am trying to prove the monotonicity of the following function.
$$f(x) = x +  \frac{\Phi'\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$$
for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where $\Phi\left(x\right)$ is normal cdf and $\Phi'\left(x\right)$ is the derivative. It seems that it is monotonically increasing in $x$, and its slope is less than 1 for all $x$.

I also wonder if $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, with $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = 0$. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833835/log-convexity-of-a-function-defined-by-an-integral-normal-mills-ratio) is very related to yours and this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4833935/195378) for example answers your question.